# How to find the users who took a long break from posting on an SE site?

Tags: support, data-explorer

I would like to find the users who took a break from posting on a particular SE site. That is, top N users by the length of time interval  between two consecutive posts.

I know that Data Explorer has all the necessary data, but I can't think of an appropriate query for the task.

Comment: For users on a single site? Not SE wide?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in a single SE site. But if you also have a cross-site query, I imagine someone else will be interested in that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [following query](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/260154/users-who-took-a-long-break-from-posting-on-an-se-site?reputation=10000) would show that for a specific site:

```
with userpostdates as 
(
  select owneruserid
       , posts.creationdate 
       , row_number() over (partition by owneruserid order by posts.creationdate) as rownum
  from posts 
  inner join users on posts.owneruserid = users.id
  where owneruserid is not null
  and owneruserid > 0 
  and users.reputation > ##reputation:int##
  and posts.posttypeid in (1,2) -- only Q and A
)

select fp.owneruserid as [User Link]
, max(datediff(d, lp.creationdate, fp.creationdate)) as diff
from userpostdates fp
inner join userpostdates lp on fp.owneruserid = lp.owneruserid 
             and fp.rownum = lp.rownum + 1
group by fp.owneruserid 
order by max(datediff(d, lp.creationdate, fp.creationdate)) desc
```

The query first determines per user the sequence of post dates. Than the difference between two rows is calculated. The results are grouped per user and the Max value is selected.

On SO this query never ends. On math.se it succeeds if you select only users with 10000 rep or more. To have one query that determines this across the SE network would probably need to run for days...

Comment: Bah, you finished just before I did, well done.

Comment: @TimStone well, I'm not sure if this is the most efficient way though... so don't give up yet....and maybe I cheated, I had a head start because it came up in the Tavern ;)

Comment: It was how I did it, so we'll assume it's correct ;)

Comment: @TimStone Just an aside, which I also mentioned  in the Tavern: tag wikis/excerpts are weird in that the creation date is taken from creation of the tag, while the owner is whoever was the first to fill it in. This is why the original version of the query showed me as an author of a post made long before I joined the site.

Comment: Nice, thanks!  How hard would it be also include the time between the most-recent post and "today", to find the people who've wandered away even if they used to post every week or two?

Comment: @MonicaCellio That's actually much easier than this query: just sort users with >=N rep by the latest post date. I'll write it up in a moment.

Comment: @MonicaCellio [Here it is](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/260162/reputed-users-who-stopped-posted?reputation=1000). (But let me know if I misunderstood the objective of query.)

Comment: @Behaviour better use modern join semantics: http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/260258/reputed-users-who-stopped-posted?reputation=1000

Answer (score 1):

Now that SO data is [available on BigQuery](http://stackoverflow.blog/2016/12/You-Can-Now-Play-With-Stack-Overflow-Data-on-Googles-BigQuery/), it is easy to run [rene's query](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/245977) on Stack Overflow, even without filtering users by reputation. It takes 10-15 seconds to complete. Because the BigQuery syntax ("Standard SQL" variant) is slightly different, and so are some column names, I include the BigQuery version at the bottom.

As of 2016-12-21, the longest gap between posts on Stack Overflow is **2803 days**, set by [mransley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18977/mransley) who posted an answer on September 26 of 2008 and came back to ask a question on May 30 of 2016.

Surprisingly, the currently longest gap between **answers** (ignoring questions) is **also 2803 days**, set by [Mackaaij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13222/mackaaij) (2008-10-01 to 2016-06-04). And the longest gap between questions (ignoring answers) is **2802 days**, set by [vengafoo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12834/vengafoo) (2008-09-23 to 2016-05-26). This is quite a coincidence.

---

```
with userpostdates as 
(
  select owner_user_id
       , posts.creation_date 
       , row_number() over (partition by owner_user_id order by posts.creation_date) as rownum
  from `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.stackoverflow_posts` as posts 
  inner join `bigquery-public-data.stackoverflow.users` as users on posts.owner_user_id = users.id
  where owner_user_id is not null
  and owner_user_id > 0 
  and posts.post_type_id in (1,2) -- only Q and A
)

select fp.owner_user_id
, max(date_diff(date(fp.creation_date), date(lp.creation_date), day)) as diff
from userpostdates fp
inner join userpostdates lp on fp.owner_user_id = lp.owner_user_id 
             and fp.rownum = lp.rownum + 1
group by fp.owner_user_id 
order by max(date_diff(date(fp.creation_date), date(lp.creation_date), day)) desc
limit 100
```